# Azure DevOps audit logs for test plans

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on script to find deleted test plans in azure DevOps.

I can find deleted projects, pipelines and repos from Azure DevOps audit logs but I am not able to see any data released to test plans.

In Azure DevOps audit logs we get action type using which I track deleted , created and removed resources.

Is their way to track Created/Deleted test plans using audit logs or any another method?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/delete-test-artifacts?view=azure-devops):

> We only support permanent deletion of test artifacts such as test
> plans, test suites, test cases, shared steps and shared parameters.
> Deleted test artifacts won't appear in the recycle bin and cannot be
> restored.
>
> When you delete test artifacts, the following actions occur:
>
> 3.Causes all information in the work item **tracking data store and TCM data store to be deleted** and cannot be reactivated nor restored.

We can know that test plan will be permanently deleted. So I am afraid it is impossible to track deleted test plans.